# Is there any possibility of two asynchronous Javascript function instances executing two blocks of code at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading, dom-events

I understand that Javascript doesn't have multiple threads, but I'd like to know if the following code has any chance of breaking.  My understanding is that unless an asynchronous function is called, such as `setTimeout` or an AJAX call, that once a block of code starts executing there's no way for it to pause until it completes or does call an asynchronous function.

Basically, users select multiple checkboxes and then hits a button that executes AJAX processing of their selections.  My goal is to have a "Saving..." icon that stays only until all the AJAX processes are complete, and after all are finished display a success message.

Barring any AJAX errors, so long as the callback function in the `jQuery.post` executes in its entirety without interruption, I don't see how the `if(numProcessed == toProcess)` would ever execute more than once or less than once.  But if two AJAX callbacks get into the callback function, both increment the `numProcessed` counter before either get to the following `if`, then it seems that the code inside would be executed twice.

```
var numProcessed = 0;
var checkedBoxes = jQuery("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
var toProcess = checkedBoxes.size();

checkedBoxes.each(function() {
  jQuery.post('somepage.php',{...},function(results) {
    numProcessed++;
    if(numProcessed == toProcess) {
      jQuery("#saving-message").remove();
      jQuery("#feedback-panel").text('Successfully processed all selections.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know javascript or browser execution well enough to know how to implement this, but if you are in complete control of the implementation of both pieces of code that do long/heavy processing, you could create two objects that have a "process next" function, keeping an internal count inside the object, and having some way to signal that processing is complete (another function, or some "completed" boolean).  Call each of them until both have finished processing.

Comment: @Merlyn: I had considered chaining so after one completes it starts the next one. My concerns were that 1) it wouldn't be as quick since between each we have to wait for the HTML request to arrive at the server rather than all queue up immediately. 2) If something fails at one link in the chain, all the remaining ones would not be processed. 3) Depending on the # of items, that might overflow the stack since it would create nested closures for each item. I might be wrong, but I'm glad I can instead rely on Javascript's single-threadedness instead of creating a more complex structure.

Comment: @Merlyn: Rereading your comment, it seems like you had a better structure planned than I did in my thoughts.  Yours would allow #2 and #3 from my comment to be solved fairly trivially, but #1 might still be an issue.

Comment: I still haven't tried to understand your original code, or question, because I'm not a web dev, hence the off-topic yaking in comments :)  So, continuing on the topic of cooperative multi-tasking... If you have X round-trips to the server both ways, I think your perf is going to be the same.  But you may be able to give incremental feedback to the user by mixing in server calls with UI updates.  If you want the UI to respond faster than that, I think you're screwed, unless you can execute a client-side callback in the middle of a server request, or you have true multi-threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one thread in JavaScript so every function that want to be execute is put in stack and have to wait until all others are execute. In your case "each" is the first  function in the stack, so every callback function have to wait and will be execute in the order they put on the stack. 
After all "numProcessed == toProcess" could only one time be true.

Comment: Very good, glad to hear that.  I think what's confusing about the single-threaded nature of Javascript is that it has these asynchronous functions that in a larger sense make me think about Javascript as sort of multi-threaded, in that it has a background process that swoops in and throws callback executions into the queue, rather than everything being absolutely procedural/synchronous.

Answer (score -2):

The rx.net team has introduced rx for javascript. Reactive extension are for asynchronous programming. they have also written for rxjs for jquery too. My be that suite your need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx